# Juggernaut or Dreadnought

Tags: word-choice

Which one sounds more dominant by definition?

Juggernaut - something (such as a force, campaign, or movement) that is extremely large and powerful and cannot be stopped.

Dreadnought - "fear nought". Mostly the largest British warships after the "age of sail".

Comment: They're completely different. _Juggernaut_ is a bad English transcription of a Hindi word designating a class of worship. _Dreadnought,_ on the ohter hand, is a Germanic word meaning _Fear Nothing_ designating a class of warship.

Comment: But 'juggernaut' is in widespread daily use in the UK. Often it specifically means a large vehicle like an articulated lorry, typically a drive unit and 40 foot trailer. People complain about 'juggernauts' coming through their quiet village etc.

Comment: @John: It's not that bad a transcription for somebody with a British accent.

Comment: What does one call the driver of a juggernaut, then? A Juggernautnaut?

Answer (score 4):

Original meanings and figurative senses of the two terms include
• *[dreadnought](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dreadnought#Noun)*, “a battleship, especially of the World War I era, in which most of the firepower is concentrated in large guns that are of the same caliber” and “One that is the largest or the most powerful of its kind”
• *[juggernaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juggernaut)*, “the Hindu Ratha Yatra temple [of [Jagannath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagannath)] car, which apocryphally was reputed to crush devotees under its wheels” and “a literal or metaphorical force regarded as mercilessly destructive and unstoppable”

To some extent, “which one sounds more dominant by definition” must be a matter of personal opinion.  I suppose a real  dreadnought is more powerful than a real juggernaut, but a metaphorical juggernaut is more fearsome than a metaphorical dreadnought.

Some other words to consider besides the above (each given in the following form: original meaning; figurative sense; and how it rates vs a metaphorical juggernaut) include:
• *[behemoth](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/behemoth#Noun)*, “(biblical) A great and mighty beast God shows Job in Job 40:15-24”;  “A great and mighty monster” or “Something which has the qualities of great power and might, and monstrous proportions”; perhaps as powerful, but certainly less malignant
• *[colossus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/colossus#Noun)*, “... certain famous statues in antiquity, as the Colossus of Nero in Rome and the Colossus of Rhodes”; “Any creature or thing of gigantic size”; plainly a patsy vs either a juggernaut or dreadnought
• *[leviathan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leviathan#Noun)*, “(biblical) A large sea monster which guards the gates of hell at the bottom of the sea”; “Something large; behemoth”; a guardian of the gates of hell ought to have some muscle and bite, so might put up a show against a juggernaut, particularly in its own element at the bottom of the sea
• *[Gargantua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargantua)*, a giant in some works of Rabelais; whence the metaphorical *[gargantuan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gargantuan#Adjective)*, “Huge; immense; tremendous”  or “Of a tremendous size, volume, degree, etc”; in the original, possibly a match for any of the above, but in metaphoric form, a pale shadow of the original.

[Wikisaurus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus%3agigantic) for *gigantic* includes some additional terms.